# GeoWebCache 1.11.0 application/json not supported for GetFeatureInfo

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, geowebcache, getfeatureinfo

I have been trying to find out whether or not I can serve a response to a GetFeatureInfo request from my GeoWebCache in a JSON format, but I have been coming up empty. My capabilities list doesn't include it, but I don't see why GeoWebCache wouldn't support it when Geoserver does.

My work around consists of altering the URL of the GetFeatureInfo call to point to my Geoserver instead of my GeoWebCache, but it feels a bit hacky if it's possible to get the JSON format through GWC.

I'm using Openlayers 4 and the built-in WMS GetFeatureInfo URL functionality.

Comment: Are you talking about the GeoWebCache embedded in GeoServer or a stand-alone one?

Comment: The stand-alone one.

Comment: If you do not see the format in GetCapabilities then it probably is not implemented. It should be a per-layer configuration but I can see only a general "queryable" element in the schema of the configuration file http://geowebcache.org/schema/docs/1.2.2/index.html. I guess that info_format just defaults to text/html.

Comment: application/json seems to work for WMTS but not for WMS (GeoWebCache 1.12.2).